# Assign month and Period to variables based on sysdate

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Original Question:
I am trying to assign month and Year values to Variables for Fiscal Year starting Apr till Mar for 18 months. I am expecting the batch to pick sys month and year and assign it for 18 months. Month variable should increment with the months value till 18 months and Year variable value should increment end of march starting Apr.

Comment: Please put the original question back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not too difficult using a little modulo math and indexing into a list of month name abbreviations. I left the mechanism to get the CUR_MONTH and CUR_YEAR up to you. You could parse %DATE%, but that would be poor. Look for ways to get the current timestamp through `WMIC`.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Use 0-based month index.
REM Jan = 0, Feb = 1, ...

FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %%a IN (`type NUL ^|WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Month ^| findstr .`) DO (SET /A "CUR_MONTH=%%a - 1")
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %%a IN (`type NUL ^|WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Year ^| findstr .`) DO (SET /A "CUR_YEAR=%%a")

SET "MONTH_LIST=JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
SET /A "FISCAL_YEAR=%CUR_YEAR%"

FOR /L %%i IN (0, 1, 17) DO (
    SET /A "MONTH_INDEX=(!CUR_MONTH! + %%i) %% 12"
    SET /A "MONTH_OFFSET=!MONTH_INDEX! * 3"

    SET /A "VAR_INDEX=%%i + 1"
    CALL SET "MONTH!VAR_INDEX!=%%MONTH_LIST:~!MONTH_OFFSET!,3%%"

    IF !MONTH_INDEX! EQU 3 (SET /A "FISCAL_YEAR=!FISCAL_YEAR! + 1")
    SET "YEAR!VAR_INDEX!=FY!FISCAL_YEAR:~2,2!"
)
SET "MONTH_LIST="
SET "MONTH_INDEX="
SET "MONTH_OFFSET="

SET MONTH
SET YEAR

EXIT /B 0
```

And the output is:

```
MONTH1=Aug
MONTH10=May
MONTH11=Jun
MONTH12=Jul
MONTH13=Aug
MONTH14=Sep
MONTH15=Oct
MONTH16=Nov
MONTH17=Dec
MONTH18=Jan
MONTH2=Sep
MONTH3=Oct
MONTH4=Nov
MONTH5=Dec
MONTH6=Jan
MONTH7=Feb
MONTH8=Mar
MONTH9=Apr
YEAR1=FY17
YEAR10=FY17
YEAR11=FY17
YEAR12=FY17
YEAR13=FY18
YEAR14=FY18
YEAR15=FY18
YEAR16=FY18
YEAR17=FY18
YEAR18=FY18
YEAR2=FY17
YEAR3=FY17
YEAR4=FY17
YEAR5=FY17
YEAR6=FY17
YEAR7=FY17
YEAR8=FY17
YEAR9=FY17
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want. The question example result shows the year changing for `YEAR7=FY17` for January. If you want it to start in April, try `SET /A "CUR_MONTH=3"`.

Comment: Perhaps I figured out what you wanted. Do you want the FISCAL YEAR to be APR-MAR? Please check the results again.

Comment: Ok, @cec4111. I think I've done just about everything for you which is not what I should do.

Comment: Thanks Liturgist, this solutions works fine. Just the year doesn't increment at Apr, instead it increments 12 months from the Month1. Appreciate your instant reply

Comment: @cec4111 - Does this float your boat? I think I may be done.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Really appreciate it.